# mongo query/aggregation with equality inside array

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to formulate a query over the sample bios collection http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bios-example-collection/:

*Retrieve all the persons who received two awards on the same year.*

The expected answers are "Ole-Johan Dahl" and "Kristen Nygaard" as for instance the doc for Ole-Johan Dahl is

`{
    "_id" : 5,
    "name" : {
        "first" : "Ole-Johan",
        "last" : "Dahl"
    },
    "birth" : ISODate("1931-10-12T04:00:00Z"),
    "death" : ISODate("2002-06-29T04:00:00Z"),
    "contribs" : [
        "OOP",
        "Simula"
    ],
    "awards" : [
        {
            "award" : "Rosing Prize",
            "year" : 1999,
            "by" : "Norwegian Data Association"
        },
        {
            "award" : "Turing Award",
            "year" : 2001,
            "by" : "ACM"
        },
        {
            "award" : "IEEE John von Neumann Medal",
            "year" : 2001,
            "by" : "IEEE"
        }
    ]
}`

So far, the best query that I could come up with is the following query using aggregation framework:

```
db.bios.aggregate([ 
    {$project : { "first_name": "$name.first", "last_name": "$name.last" , "award1" :"$awards", "award2" :"$awards" } },
    {$unwind : "$award1"},
    {$unwind : "$award2"},
    {$project : {  "first_name": 1, "last_name": 1, "award1" : 1, "award2" : 1,
    "super" : { $and : [  {$eq : ["$award1.year", "$award2.year"]}, 
        {$lt: ["$award1.award", "$award2.award"]} 
       ]
     }}
    },
    {$match : {"super": true}}
])
```

However I am not happy with this solution because

1. the query projects awards twice and unwind them in the following step. This will generate quadratic many intermediate documents;
2. the query computes an auxiliary field "super" which is only used for filtering afterwards.

Is there a better way to formulate this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following aggregation pipeline:

```
db.bios.aggregate([
    {
        "$unwind": "$awards"
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "year": "$awards.year",
                "firstName": "$name.first",
                "lastName": "$name.last"
            },
            "count": { "$sum": 1 },
            "award_recepients": { "$push": "$name" }
        }
    },
    {
        "$match": { "count": 2 }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "year": "$_id.year",
            "award_recepients": 1,
            "count": 1
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Group definitely solves my problem. However, actually I have a more general question in mind no only using the  "$eq" operation for comparison. For instance, if we want to ask queries like "Retrieve all the persons who received at least two awards within an interval of 5 years", do you have some idea on how to formulate this query?

Comment: I double checked your answer. I got more answers with your query. https://gist.github.com/ghxiao/b3965fabb423387c61cc

Comment: @stderr Try the updated answer, that should now give the correct results (untested).